# Neo4j - Mapping CQL Return Result to List<POJO>

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-neo4j-4

I created CQL query to return multiple list objects.But this object values are combined from two different arrays.I want to parse this list of values to List objects without using manual parsing using JPA or OGM.

In my POJO class :

```
private String DIST_ID;

private long PV;

private String POST_DATE;
```

In my repo interface :

```
@Query("MATCH(DST:Distributor) WITH DST AS DSTS, DST.PV AS array_one, DST.POST_DATE AS array_two UNWIND RANGE(0, SIZE(array_one) - 1) AS i WITH{DIST_ID: DSTS.DIST_ID ,PV: array_one[i],POST_DATE: array_two[i]} AS Odh RETURN Odh;")
public List<List<String>> getAllPVForMonth();
```

When I call this method I am getting below result[Tested in Junit]

```
[{DIST_ID=305594091, PV=110, POST_DATE=28-Sep-16}, {DIST_ID=305594191, PV=503, POST_DATE=30-Sep-16}]
```

I want to convert this result in to List of pojo objects.I don't want parse  `List<List<String>>` to `List<POJO>`.Any idea please share your input's.

Comment: I don't have much experience with Spring, but have you tried to define an interface as projection? http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections

Answer (score 1):

It seems this is described in the official [Spring data Neo4j documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/4.1.5.RELEASE/reference/html/#reference_programming-model_mapresult)

```
public interface MovieRepository extends GraphRepository<Movie> {

    @Query("MATCH (movie:Movie)-[r:RATING]->(), (movie)<-[:ACTS_IN]-(actor:Actor) " +
           "WHERE movie.id={0} " +
           "RETURN movie as movie, COLLECT(actor) AS 'cast', AVG(r.stars) AS 'averageRating'")
    MovieData getMovieData(String movieId);

    @QueryResult
    public class MovieData {
        Movie movie;
        Double averageRating;
        Set<Actor> cast;
    }

}
```